# PM2 + pocketbase - works when launched directly but not thru ecosystem file

Tags: node.js, pm2, pocketbase

Since pm2 repo is completely abandoned I decided to search for luck here.

When I'm launching pocketbase process using `pm2 start pocketbase -- serve --http=127.0.0.1:8097`
then `curl 127.0.0.1:8097` I get `{"code":404,"message":"Not Found.","data":{}}` **which is expected** as it's just root of the process. So far so good.

But what I really need to do is launch it from pm2 ecosystem file. Here's my config:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "dev-db",
    script: "./pocketbase",
    args: ['serve', '--http', '127.0.0.1:8097'],
    interpreter: "none",
  }]
};
```

but then when it's run with pm2 (`pm2 start dev-db.js`)
the process launches and also is seen as online, but the service in inaccessible:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8097
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8097: Connection refused
```

Current shape of `args` as an array I've found in an issue as a solution - to use it instead of string, but that didn't work. defining interpreter as `none` also doesn't work.
Also tried to add

```
    env: {
      PORT: 8097
    }
```

to the config, but no luck.

Went over 100s of issues on the [abandoned pm2 repo](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues) but nothing I've found have been related or worked.

Probably unrelated but the server is setup on litespeed

**EDIT**: I think this might have something to do with PM2 having their own `serve` command [see](https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/reference/pm2-cli/#:%7E:text=serve%7Cexpose%20%5Bpath%5D%20%5Bport%5D)

I've also tried wrapping pocketbase invocation into nodejs child process adn then starting that from ecosystem file:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const pocketbase = spawn('./pocketbase', ['serve', '--http=127.0.0.1:8097']);

pocketbase.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

pocketbase.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

pocketbase.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`PocketBase process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

but that did not work.

Comment: why pm2? better approach would be to register a systemd service that will auto start/restart the PocketBase service.
eg: https://pocketbase.io/docs/going-to-production/#minimal-setup